# Translation of electrical connection gender names into non-Indo-European languages

Tags: gender, translation

The "male/female" terminology used to identify the two halves of many, if not all, connectors and fasteners seems universal in the Western Indo-European speaking world.

Do other language families use this same analogy to sexual intercourse as the IE languages do? If not, how do they describe connectors?

Comment: Interesting question, especially if the answerer can extend it to a more general answer, not localised to electric connection socket in Islamic countries

Comment: Since this question is about translation and cultural norms rather than the science of linguistics, I am voting to close, since such questions are not on topic here.

Comment: @Aaron: I disagree. This is perfect for here, the interaction between social norms and linguistic expression.

Comment: I agree with Aaron. This is an example of a question which would be on-topic on languages.SE but off-topic on linguistics.SE because it does not involve the science of linguistics.

Comment: <sigh> I'm not sure there is an appropriate SE site for this question.  I'll try Area 51.

Comment: @Tom: Maybe [Culture exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/17087/culture-exchange)?

Comment: If this were made a question about language families and not cultural conservativeness, it would be appropriate here. And as it turns out, both Arabic and Hebrew use the same "male/female" terminology used in Europe.

Comment: I think it's (as it's formulated now) a valid question relating to cross-cultural / cross-linguistic terminology.

Comment: To the specific question originally asked: Arabic uses [ذكر](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%B0%D9%83%D8%B1) 'dakar', which is unambiguously a reference to the male sexual member as found [here](http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AC%D9%87%D8%A9_%D8%B1%D9%82%D9%85%D9%8A%D8%A9_%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%A6%D9%8A%D8%A9). Hebrew similarly.

Comment: The gender specifications for the connectors in Russian I encountered very rarely and only recently, obviously under influence of English. This is uncommon and confusing. Instead Russian uses different nouns for those types of connectors (вилка/розетка "fork/rosette" for big ones, штепсель(also штекер)/гнездо (a german term/"nest") for small ones). There is no generic term for the both connector types in Russian.